# How does facebook make your comment appear right after you typed it

Tags: ajax, facebook, comments

Im tryng to build out the same type of functionality where users can comment another another users post out how would i get it to appear right away, Is it an ajax call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They send it to the server with ajax (to save it in db), and append it manually, like that https://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: I'm not sure if their ajax calls are that fast, but it's possible as well.